# Is there a way to find in forms .save() method if Model Form is creating a new record or updating existing one?

Tags: django, django-forms

What I am doing to know if the form is creating a new record or updating existing one is

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def save(self, commit=True):
        _new = True if not self.instance.id else False
        keyword = super(MyForm, self).save()
        if _new:
            do_something()
        return keyword
```

Is there some other way to find it out after super(MyForm, self).save() is called without checking for it explicitly before calling "super" like I am doing with "_new"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no other way to do it.  `ModelForm` has no fields to indicate that object is created or updated.  In fact you can pass to `ModelForm` the unsaved model as the `instance` and in this case the form will not construct the object at all:

```
form = MyForm(instance=MyModel())
```

So checking of the `self.instance.pk` is the only way for this task.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will wait for some other reply and if no other way to do it comes up I will mark your answer as accepted. I have also tried to check for form's attributes with dir(self) but no attribute seemed to be for this purpose

Comment: I read the source code of the `BaseModelForm` so I am pretty sure that there is no such attributes :-)

Answer (score 5):

It's just the the `.id`  (actually `.pk`) field.  If it's `None` (potentially any 'falsy' value), then it's a new record and `.save()` will use `INSERT`.  Otherwise it's the key to the existing record and it will use an `UPDATE`.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#how-django-knows-to-update-vs-insert

Comment: That is what I am doing now "Checking for self.instance.id before calling super().save()". But once "super().save()"  is called ".id" does have value so cannot be used for this purpose.

Comment: right, I was just linking to the docs where it explains how it's done inside Django.

Comment: A reminder: by default, `pk` can be 0, which is 'falsy'. Always explicitly check that `pk` is or is not `None`.